# chef || rescue block does not work in case of exception

Tags: ruby, nunit, chef-infra, nexus, chef-recipe

I have the below snippet in my chef recipe.

```
begin
     execute 'run_tests' do
         command comand_string_to_run_nUnint
         user "user"
         password passkey
     end
ensure      
    execute 'upload_report' do 
        command uplaod
        user "user"
        password passkey
     end
end
```

the problem is that the report is being uploaded successfully in case of all test passed, but fails to upload when there is a failure in any of the test case.

how do I ensure the report is uploaded in all cases.

is there a different way to handle exceptions?

ps: I am uploading to artifact repository named Nexus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ignore_failure true` for your `execute[run_tests]` resource. This way Chef will continue to run the recipe, even if this command exits with error code.

```
execute 'run_tests' do
     ignore_failure true
     command comand_string_to_run_nUnint
     user "user"
     password passkey
 end
```

Another possibility is to use `returns` property for `execute[run_tests]` resource. When there are test failures the "comand_string_to_run_nUnint" exits with non-zero code, you can add this non-zero code (for example 2) to `returns` property. This way Chef will think that everything is ok and still continue to run the recipe.

```
execute 'run_tests' do
     returns [0, 2]
     command comand_string_to_run_nUnint
     user "user"
     password passkey
 end
```